# Jest: return a value from a test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I would like to get the `result` (the returned value) of a test in another test (the next test) with Jest. Is there a way to do this?

I tried to return a value, but I don't now how to catch it and affect it to a const or a var.

```
test('a', () => {
  expect(1).toBe(1)
  return 'ok'
})

test('b', () => {
  // I want to use the value returned by the first test: "ok"
})
```

I know i can use "global" variable, but I feel like it's a bit hacky.

Is there a way to get the returned value of a test callback in order to use it in another test?

Comment: Not like that, test is used by jest/jasmine as a void type of function. To achieve what you want I suggest having a toplevel object,  a file in which you store such info or even a dedicated server that keeps track of data not only per run, but per suite/project/etc.I can elaborate either one of the approaches I recommend.

Comment: As I recall unit testing should test individual units of code. You don't need to have the result of the first test. [See here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/287546/unit-testing-functions-calling-other-tested-functions)

Comment: @RamyHerrira You are right. In my *actual* case, it's not unit test (jest can drive any kind of tests). It's in a `describe` block where some tests are done in a specific order, because it tests a whole scenario. So it uses Jest but it's not unit test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single execution, you could have a top level object that stores execution information, which you parse in an `afterAll` method.

Here is a dummy test suite which highlights what I mean. Of course you can get creative and be more organized, and have objects even at a higher level.

You could then store them in a file, send the results to a server, etc.

**test.js**

```
describe('A suite', () => {

  let suiteSpecificData = {};

  test('a test', () => {
    expect(1).toBe(1)
    suiteSpecificData["a test"] = "ok"
  })

  test('another test', () => {
    let theOtherTestData = suiteSpecificData["a test"];
    let thisTestData = suiteSpecificData["another test"] = {};

    if (theOtherTestData === "ok") {
       thisTestData.messageOne = "All good with the other test";
       thisTestData.someMoreRandomStuff = [1,2,3];
    }
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(suiteSpecificData));
  });
});
```